# Data Extension date fields for Insert and Update

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I feel like I am missing something. We are trying to set-up INSERT_DATE and UPDATE_DATE fields for a Data Extension. These fields would not exist in the file being imported.

What we would like is when a new records is added through the Import the INSERT_DATE and UPDATE_DATE fields are populated with the current system time. This should be able to be handled by setting the fields to not Nullable and using the Use Current Date for the Default Value.

Where I am stuck is how can I ensure the UPDATE_DATE field is marked with the Current Date a row is updated and not updating the INSERT_DATE ever?

Is this possible and I'm missing the obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way set an *updated date* on a row via import.

What I have done in the past is set up two data extensions -- one Staging (no primary keys, every column is larger than needed and nullable) and one Master (proper primary keys and field precisions).

I import and overwrite the Staging every time and then use a Query Activity to insert or update the rows in the Master.

You could use the Staging -> Master query to conditionally set both the Insert and Update Date columns.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation Adam. That's what I expected. I was pushing the client to add the update date to their export that we will consume. Their expectation was SFMC should be able to handle an Update and Insert date.